# Is there any kind of standard for console/command line programming

Tags: standards, console-application, pipe

I mean, I'd like my programs to be reusable later, like the Unix utilities (by using pipes, for example)

If there isn't any, can you give me some tips?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard unix command line utilities are "simple", in that they accept some input, do some processing, then produce output. As long as your utilities can read from stdin (input) and write output to stdout, they can be chained together with pipes.

Comment: That's it. The core concepts in Unix system are very simple. "Everything is a file" is the big one.

Comment: Can you suggest me a very simple utility to read its source code?

Comment: I thought I had to redirect standard input or something like that. Well, it's better than I expected :)

Comment: even the simplest utilities these days are fairly "complex" internally, but I'd suggest grabbing a copy of GNU coreutils and go from there.